# flask app on / location interferes with static location /pathname on nginx

Tags: nginx

I have a server where I want to host 2 flask apps and 1 static website. This is how the config looks:

```
server {
    # Redirect http requests to https
    listen 80;

    server_name site.example.com;
    return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    include snippets/self-signed.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    server_name site.example.com;

    location /api {
        # Flask App-2
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass https://localhost:8081/api;
    }
    location /swaggerui {
        # Swagger UI for Flask App-2
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass https://localhost:8081/swaggerui;
    }
    location / {
        # Flask App-1
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass https://localhost:8080;
    }
    location /new {
        # Website-1
        root /data/ui-project;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

Flask App-1, Flask App-2 and Swagger UI for Flask App-2 are working fine. Both Flask Apps are served via gunicorn.

The problem that I am facing is that the /new path is getting hit on "/" path by Flask App-1. I have tried to move /new to the top of the list (above /api), update it's location to "location = /new" but they don't work.

Is there any way to get /new working without having to modify the Flask App-1 on "/"?

Comment: Using `/index.html` as the last element of your `try_files` statement will always send the request to flask app 1. `index.html` should be located under `/data/ui-project/new`, and you should be using `try_files $uri $uri/ /new/index.html;`